# Python web3 return value of getBlock(full_transactions=True)

Tags: web3.py, python

I am trying to get the meaning of all fields returned by getBlock, but no where to find!

```
web3.eth.getBlock(block_identifier='pending', full_transactions=True)
```

returns a list of :

```
AttributeDict({'blockHash': HexBytes('0x50edaaa071801750cb71d5b89b23a98e4ac911a3451acfa1646ee45a45200902'),
   'blockNumber': 11633063,
   'from': '0xA2F4442B71267F12A6844bb9b93cb744F0217baF',
   'gas': 243390,
   'gasPrice': 132000000000,
   'hash': HexBytes('0x630a3fc021744bb400437578464b4c4f3eeea82b3e1f58d3a2483e2cb0fbe9e1'),
   'input': '0x1e83409a000000000000000000000000a2f4442b71267f12a6844bb9b93cb744f0217baf',
   'nonce': 4,
   'r': HexBytes('0x02c77d2251fbd4b97aa0285e7b7651ff7775b8d41f3c5c42925a30ae087a6fdb'),
   's': HexBytes('0x4e8c0bb1e73ed38dc02a3a22167507b2572e1a18440a054ac421f2342f8b6fd9'),
   'to': '0x098e1708b920EFBdD7afe33Adb6a4CBa30c370B9',
   'transactionIndex': 87,
   'v': 28,
   'value': 0})
```

Could anyone provide some explanation of those fields (especially input, r, s and v).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `full_transactions` returns a list of multiple `getTransactionByHash` call results.

You can find the description of Ethereum JSON-RPC API fields here:

https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API